# relative polar coordinates for TikZ elements in axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to annotate a patch plot with lines whose start and end points are given in absolute polar and relative polar coordinates, respectively.

The patch plot, based on *cartesian* data, comes out as a circular shape centred around the origin (0,0) and shall be simulated here by a plain circle.

Lines should start at the circumference of the shape and point away from the shape under a given angle and have a well defined length. Therefore, the use of ***relative*** polar coordinates for the line's ***end*** point.

What seems to be straightforward with TikZ (left) fails inside the `axis` environment of pgfplots (right): neither the inclination angle nor the length of the line are correct if relative polar coordinates are used.

[image]

What is wrong with the rel. polar coordinates here?

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) circle[radius=0.01];
  \draw[blue] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
  \draw[thick] (45:1) -- ++(45:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[tiny,enlargelimits,
  axis equal,
  xmin=-2,xmax=2,
  ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
  ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
  grid=major,
  ]
  \draw[blue] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
  \draw[blue, dashdotted] (0,0) -- (45:2);
  \draw[thick] (45:1) -- ++(45:0.5);
%  \draw[thick] (45:1) -- (45:1.5); %absolute coordinates do work
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `pgfplots` documentation states

> As noted in the documentation for `axis cs`, adding two coordinates by means of the TikZ `++` operator may have unexpected effects. The correct way for `++` operations is `axis direction cs:`.

Unfortunately, there are not implicit polar coordinates (`angle:radius`) for the `axis direction cs:`, which is why you have to compute these yourself (but it's easy).  So we end up with

```
%\draw[thick] (45:1) -- ++(45:0.5);
\draw[thick] (45:1) -- ++(axis direction cs:{0.5*cos(45)},{0.5*sin(45)});
```