# How to specify length with \draw such that it matches axis units in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a MWE in which a line is provided by length and angle with \draw. The units for length I provided is cm, which is not consistent with the axis units. I need 2 units (cm,em,.. ?) in \draw to be 2 units on the axis, i.e., the first line from (1,1) should end at (1,3). How should I represent length \draw such that the units of length and axis are consistent?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.9,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        cycle list name=exotic,
        ]
        \addplot+[solid,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,10) (1,1)};
        \addplot+[dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(10,1) (1,10)};
        \addplot+[loosely dotted,line width=1.0pt] coordinates {(1,1) (1,10)};
        \draw (1,1) -- ++(0:2cm) -- ++(90:3cm);
        \draw[solid,line width=1.0pt] (axis cs:5.5,5.5) circle [radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323480/relative-polar-coordinates-for-tikz-elements-in-axis-environment

Comment: Note also that you need `\draw (axis cs:1,1)`, or set the `compat` version to 1.11 or higher, in which case `axis cs` is default.