# Absolute and relative polar coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

Today i encountered some weird behaviour (lines with off angles and wrong lengths) while creating graphics with TikZ/PGF. After some searching i have narrowed down the problem to the example shown below:

Here i am trying to create a line of length 10 that starts at (0/0) and has a 30° slope *using polar coordinates*.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ymin=-1.5, ymax=15.5,
            xmin=-1.5, xmax=20.5,
            grid=major
        ]
            \draw [blue] (0,0) -- ++(30:10);
            \draw [green] (0,0) -- (30:10);
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=10];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To my mind, the blue and the green line should be identical, but for some reason that i cannot explain, they are not.

Here is how i understand it:

The only difference between the two commands

```
\draw [blue] (0,0) -- ++(30:10);
\draw [green] (0,0) -- (30:10);
```

is that the first uses relative coordinates and the second does not. But since the first command uses the last part of the path as its point of reference (0/0) and the second command uses the origin of the coordinate system as its point of reference (0/0) [TikZ/PGF manual, section 13.2.1] there should be no difference.

Since my prediction of what should happen does not match with reality, obviously i am missing something. I would be glad if somebody could give me a hint as to what it is that i don't understand here.

Thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323480/relative-polar-coordinates-for-tikz-elements-in-axis-environment/323489#323489