# pgfplots, lengths in axis coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, lengths, axis

Sorry if it's a FAQ, probably looking for the wrong keywords but couldn't find anything.

I have a macro that takes a length parameter to draw a shape. I'd like to call this macro inside a pgfplots axis. And I'd like to have the length parameter in axis coordinates units.

Now, I know how to specify absolute coordinates with `(axis cs: x,y)` but is there a way to get the axis unit length?

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% draw a circle of radius #1 with randomness #2
\newcommand\irregularcircle[2]{%
  \pgfextra {%
    \pgfmathsetseed{42}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
  +(0:\len pt)
  \foreach \a in {20,40,...,340}{
    \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
    -- +(\a:\len pt)
  } -- cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xmin=-8, xmax=8,
    ymin=-8, ymax=8,
    ]
    \draw[rounded corners=2mm, fill=black, opacity=0.2] (axis cs:0,0) \irregularcircle{2cm}{2mm};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to give the circle radius and randomness (`\irregularcircle{}{}`) in axis units instead of `cm` and `mm`.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. sure, see the edit

Comment: You basically just need to do this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323489/, and remove all explicit lengths (`pt`, `mm`, `cm`).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks, completely missed those `pt` lengths in the macro. But while this could fix this specific example, it doesn't answer how to get the unit length from the current plot in axis coordinates

Comment: But why do you need it? If you use `\irregularcircle{2}{0.2}` for example, and `+(axis direction cs:{cos(\a)*\len},{sin(\a)*\len})` in the macro, that coordinate will be in axis units, so your "circle" will have a radius of 2 in the axis units.

Comment: You're right, thank you! I don't really need it at this point, it was more out of curiosity, in case I need it for a different problem in the future