# Shaded circle sector within axis environment with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following command works in 'plain' TikZ;

```
\fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- +(45:2) arc (45:-45:2);
```

but it does not(?) work inside the `\begin{axis}` environment.

Any solution? TIA.

Comment: I use this version (at Overleaf). Could it be a local error at Overleaf?

Comment: @marmot Does that work on your machine? (In the sense that it gives the expected output.) mf67: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323480/relative-polar-coordinates-for-tikz-elements-in-axis-environment

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If you mean that the arc is not in axis coordinates, I agree. There are many different interpretation of what "does not work" might mean, and the link you shared my very well be what the OP is really asking for.

Comment: @marmot. Inside the axis environment it looks odd, going off the 'axis' area directly and is cropped. Outside the axis environment it looks perfect.

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? As mentioned there, relative polar coordinates does not work inside an `axis`. If you remove the `+` you get something more reasonable.

Comment: Many thanks. It seems to work now.