# PGFPLOTS circle radius scaling issue

Tags: pgfplots, circles

I'm working on a set of graphs that contain circles drawn at various locations. I'm using the `circle` command to draw the circles on the graphs, but I'm not able to set the circle radii such that they match the axes scales. That is to say, a circle with a radius of 1 does not have a radius of 1 with respect to the x or y axes.

To figure out my problem, I turned to the manual. Unfortunately I cannot even reproduce the basic circle plot shown in the manual. The code below taken directly from the manual (I had to add the document class) produces what looks like an ellipsis and not the circle shown in the manual.

```
% MWE from manual (Revision 1.16, page 355)
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[tiny,enlargelimits,
   axis equal,
   xmin=-1,xmax=1,
   ymin=-1,ymax=1,
   xtick={-1,0,1},
   ytick={-1,0,1},
   grid=major,
]
   \draw [blue] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One of the other answers here said the proper syntax should have a radius with a unit. Adding `cm` to the radius parameter as shown below produces a circle at the origin with a radius that goes beyond the x=1 plane.

```
   \draw [blue] (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
```

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to reproduce from the Revision 1.16 manual. I am compiling using lualatex with MikTex 2.9 on Windows 10. Any thoughts on how I could reproduce the circle as shown in the manual would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527744/194703. A fix is underway.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Thank you for the link. From the link you provided, I eventually ended up on this page https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/832 where a patch was recently posted. Once I applied the patch, the old circle syntax produced the desired circle.

Comment: For the record: The "problem" was fixed in PGFPlots v1.17. Thus, your code works perfectly fine again.