# Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

A document I could compile last year now gives the error in the title. I freshly updated my texlive 2019 again, to no avail.

I could cut my code to the following MNWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5,ymin=0,ymax=5]
\draw [fill=black] (2.8469202923297705,0) circle (1.5pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Setting compat to 1.5 gets rid of the error, as does removing any one of the four viewport specifications xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.

However, in those circumstances the code does compile but the resulting plots are not looking right (it seems all the points are at the same place).

Last year I used to compile with compat=1.15.

I manually reverted pgfplots to version 1.15 but the problem persists.

Comment: Use ‘circle[radius=1.5pt]’ instead of ‘circle (1.5pt)’.

Comment: Excellent ! This should be an answer !

Comment: I think your question is, unfortunately, a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527744/194703.

Comment: See also https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/