# Set axis ratio / scale in pgfplots axis in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I've got the following `tikzpicture` setup where I'm drawing a circle on top of an x-y plane. I'm using the axis environment from the `pgfplot`package, however by setting the x and y limits my graph is scaled incorrectly in the x-axis (*i.e.,* the circle is no longer a circle).

Is there a way to maintain that the size of a unit in the x direction and a unit in the y direction are equal?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=-3, ymax=8,
        xmin=-4, xmax=4,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ytick={4},
        yticklabels={$a$},
        xtick=none,
    ]
        \draw (0, 4) circle (3);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: oval with width greater than height]

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer the question because you do not indicate which pgfplots version you are using. This is important here because of [these complications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527727/194703), which will/are solved in the most recent versions. It might well be that `axis equal` helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=-3, ymax=8,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick={4},
    yticklabels={$a$},
    axis equal image  % <---
            ]
\draw (0, 4) circle[radius=3]; % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=-3, ymax=8,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick={4},
    yticklabels={$a$},
            ]
\draw (0, 4) circle[radius=1.5cm]; % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `axis equal` is exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Where does `radius=1.5cm` come from? I think in general this is wrong. Imagine the OP has `\pgfplotsset{width=16cm}` somewhere. @TobiasEdwards Well, `axis equal` was suggested [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536222/set-axis-ratio-scale-in-pgfplots-axis-in-tikz#comment1354622_536222), not in this answer.

Comment: Sure, I think the initial suggestion is better than the latter, which is hardcoding the radius.

Comment: For reference, I needed `axis equal image` not just `axis equal` for the `xmin` and `xmax` attributes to work as desired.