# pgfplots circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circles

I'm trying to draw a circle in pgfplots. This is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[ 
                axis lines = middle,
                axis line style={->},
                ymin=-3, ymax = 3,
                xmin=-3, xmax=3,
                xlabel={$\mathrm{Re}(z)$},
                ylabel={$\mathrm{Im}(z)$},
                axis equal image
                ]
                \draw (axis cs:-1,0) circle [radius=1];
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I need the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` otherwise the radius is not interpreted in "coordinates". When I compile, I obtain the following picture, which does not look at all like a circle of radius 1 centered in -1,0. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: It looks fine on mine with `xelatex`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`. (Tex Live 2021, Ubuntu 20)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20, Tex Live 2019, compiling with ```pdflatex```

Comment: Strange indeed, I find Tex Live from 2018 can work perfectly (tested on Overleaf). Can it be an installation problem?

Comment: I found this 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527727/distorted-circles-in-axis-environment-with-tikz
which seems to address the issue

Comment: It works fine compiling with recent MikTeX. BTW, with your version of `pgfplots` you can draw circle with `\draw (-1,0) circle [radius=1];`.

Comment: I think that this https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/commit/34c3f2ef3606d09bdeee306a02884126f8bdc975 fixed it.